# unset extract variables in php from within class method

Tags: php, unset

```
<?php
namespace foo;
class bar{
  public static function runner( $data )
  {

     extract ($data);

     foreach( $elements as $element )
     {
        $varsToWipe = array_keys($element);
        extract( $element );

        /*
            bunch of code using the variables extracted from $element, eg   if( isset($runnerSpeed) )
        */

        //now i want to be able to unset all the elements set from the extract within the foreach loop
        foreach( $varsToWipe as $var )
        {
            //but what goes here in the unset function?
            \unset(  );
        }
     }

  }
}
```

How can I unset the variables extracted from within the foreach loop in the runner method?

The contents of $data can vary and the vars need to be unset so as not used again on the next loop iteration. I know i can ref the array itself but would be quicker to write if this could work...

Thanks,
John

A simpler foreach example:

```
$array = range(0,6);
$i = 0;
foreach( $array as $a )
{
   echo $i.' ';
   if( $i == 0 )
  {
    $egg = true;
  }
  ++$i;
  if( isset($egg) )
  {
     echo 'eggs ';
  }
}
```

will print

> 0 eggs 1 eggs 2 eggs 3 eggs 4 eggs 5 eggs 6 eggs

You could then add a removal of $egg from the globals as this is where is sits:

```
$array = range(0,6);

$i = 0;

foreach( $array as $a )
{
   echo $i.' ';
   if( $i == 0 )
  {
    $egg = true;
  }
  else
  {
     unset( $GLOBALS['egg'] );
  }
  ++$i;
  if( isset($egg) )
  {
     echo 'eggs ';
  }
}
```

Now it would print:

> 0 eggs 1 2 3 4 5 6

But what do you unset when you are within a class method, where is the variable actually stored?

Comment: The extracted vars should go out of scope automatically when function execution terminates

Comment: function execution, does that include the foreach function?

Comment: No, it's when the `runner` function terminates: standard PHP variable scope rules

Comment: yup, so the second iteration of the foreach loop.. any var set in the first iteration and not reset in the second will therefore persist. This is what i am trying to cleanup.. or am I mistaken?

Comment: Why are you doing the `extract` in the first place: it causes major problems because you have no idea what the variables are called: why can't you simply use the `$data` array in the first place.

Comment: because i'm feeling quite lazy.. and like hunting for shortcuts that do not harm code efficiency :)

Comment: The lazy (and the sensible) approach is the same: don't use `extract` but iterate over the array

Comment: yes, but if there were an extact opposite to extract, ie a function to unset the extracted vars then i would not need to type out full paths to the array and could simply call the variable directly. But as you can't then the best way will be to type out the full paths instead. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `extract()` function in the first place and simply iterate over the given array.

```
<?php

class Foo {

  public function runner($data) {
    foreach ($data as $delta => $element) {
      if ($element === "something") {
        // do something
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Of course you could unset something inside the array now, but why would you want to? I can't see a reason why because the array isn't passed by reference and isn't used after the loop so it will go out of scope and is simply collected by the garbage collector.

In case of nested arrays:

```
foreach ($data as $delta => $element) {
  if (is_array($element)) {
    foreach ($element as $deltaInner => $elementInner) {
      // ...
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for when $element in your code above is an assoc array.

Comment: If you have nested arrays nest the loops, I'll extend the answer with nested arrays.

Comment: Well, seems it was worth a try. The ideal solution for me would be to be able to extract $delta then at the end of the iteration unset all vars extracted from $delta.

Comment: I know how to use the foreach loop.. I won't be using a foreach loop in the final code anyway. The overhead in comparison to a std for is quite a lot more in comparison. I was just looking for an answer to the exact opposite of extract: http://webconfiguration.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/php-and-foreach.html

Comment: You only add an additional function call that is pretty much not necessary. Directly starting the loop is your fastest option.

Comment: yea, i know.. maybe i'm just being lazy tonight :) and cannot be bothered typing out the full path to the array pos is all

Comment: Don't bother comparing the performance of various loop constructs, use the one that is most useful in your situation (maintainability, readability, ...). A `while` loop would be even faster btw. ;)

Comment: hahaaa.. checkmate! But a foreach on large data sets can kill (well, not kill) your app. As a for is a shortcut to a while i suppose there will be some more time to shave, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late now but for reference.

You can unset() them directly with:

```
unset($$var);
```

What extract does is equivalent to:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

So to unset you do:

```
foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key) {
    unset($$key);
}
```

But like mentioned, you don't need to unset() them as they are deleted when the function completes as they will become out of scope.

Also, extract() is totally fine as it (most likely) does not copy the data values, it just creates new symbols for each array key. PHP internally will only copy the values if you actually modify it ie. copy-on-write with reference counting.

You can off course test this using memory_get_usage() before and after you do extract() on a large array.